# ns3 How to create a custom point to point topology

Tags: c++, simulation, ns-3

Creating a point to point topology involves two nodes and the code generating such topology is like this:

```
// Default Network Topology
//
//       10.1.1.0
// n0 -------------- n1
//    point-to-point
//
 
using namespace ns3;

NS_LOG_COMPONENT_DEFINE ("FirstScriptExample");

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CommandLine cmd (__FILE__);
  cmd.Parse (argc, argv);
  
  Time::SetResolution (Time::NS);
  LogComponentEnable ("UdpEchoClientApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
  LogComponentEnable ("UdpEchoServerApplication", LOG_LEVEL_INFO);

  NodeContainer nodes;
  nodes.Create (2);

  PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;
  pointToPoint.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("5Mbps"));
  pointToPoint.SetChannelAttribute ("Delay", StringValue ("2ms"));

  NetDeviceContainer devices;
  devices = pointToPoint.Install (nodes);

  InternetStackHelper stack;
  stack.Install (nodes);

  Ipv4AddressHelper address;
  address.SetBase ("10.1.1.0", "255.255.255.0");

  Ipv4InterfaceContainer interfaces = address.Assign (devices);

  UdpEchoServerHelper echoServer (9);

  ApplicationContainer serverApps = echoServer.Install (nodes.Get (1));
  serverApps.Start (Seconds (1.0));
  serverApps.Stop (Seconds (10.0));

  UdpEchoClientHelper echoClient (interfaces.GetAddress (1), 9);
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("MaxPackets", UintegerValue (1));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("Interval", TimeValue (Seconds (1.0)));
  echoClient.SetAttribute ("PacketSize", UintegerValue (1024));

  ApplicationContainer clientApps = echoClient.Install (nodes.Get (0));
  clientApps.Start (Seconds (2.0));
  clientApps.Stop (Seconds (10.0));

  Simulator::Run ();
  Simulator::Destroy ();
  return 0;
}
```

This code just creates two point to point nodes.
But how we can create a point to point topology with more than 2 nodes like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are [several layout helpers for PointToPointNetDevices](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/group__point-to-point-layout.html), but none of them perfectly fit what you're trying to do.

The most straightforward way to achieve the topology you want is to create the nodes, and manually install PointToPointNetDevices. Something along the lines of

```cpp
NodeContainer nodes(7);
PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;
NetDeviceContainer devices;

devices.Add(pointToPoint.Install(nodes.Get(0), nodes.Get(1)));
devices.Add(pointToPoint.Install(nodes.Get(0), nodes.Get(2)));
devices.Add(pointToPoint.Install(nodes.Get(1), nodes.Get(3)));
devices.Add(pointToPoint.Install(nodes.Get(2), nodes.Get(3)));
devices.Add(pointToPoint.Install(nodes.Get(2), nodes.Get(4)));
devices.Add(pointToPoint.Install(nodes.Get(2), nodes.Get(6)));
devices.Add(pointToPoint.Install(nodes.Get(4), nodes.Get(6)));
devices.Add(pointToPoint.Install(nodes.Get(5), nodes.Get(5)));

// the rest of your script
```

Comment: @Zahra does this answer your question?

Comment: That wasn't in the scope of your question, but you just need to create separate NetDeviceContainers and add the devices returned by `pointToPoint.Install(...)` to the NetDeviceContainer you want. Similarly you can create separate NodeContainers.

Comment: @Zahra you should accept the question here as it answers the original question